# Map Error "Not a legal formal parameter" in Scala

Tags: dictionary, intellij-idea

I wrote a small program using Scala 3 and IntelliJ:

object MapExample {

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val capital = Map( "Mexico" => "CDMX",
                     "United States" => "Washington",
                     "France" => "Paris" )
  println(capital)
}
```

}

but compiler throws "not a legal formal parameter" at the beginning of each Key, I mean in "Mexico", "United States", and "France".

What could be wrong?, I already review the version of the JDK => 11, but apparently, everything looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error, basically in:

`val capital = Map( "Mexico" => "CDMX", "United States" => "Washington", "France" => "Paris" );`

Arrow characters must be substituted:

- Instead of using => it must be used ->

Previous val assignment should be rewritter as:

`val capital = Map( "Mexico" -> "CDMX", "United States" -> "Washington", "France" -> "Paris" );`